# Can't invoke the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I got problems during my invoke.

1.) I rund following command:

```sh
peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted \
    --channelID mychannel \
    --name basic \
    --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

*--> till here everything worked well.*

Than I wanted to invoke the chaincode:

```sh
peer chaincode invoke \
    -o localhost:7050 \
    --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem \
    -C mychannel \
    -n basic \
    --peerAddresses localhost:7051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
    --peerAddresses localhost:9051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
    -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

Afterwards I got the *Error*:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 93.....: could not launch chaincode basic_1.0:465......: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1"
```

I tried the whole process serveral times, to make sure, that I do not have any mistakes before.
I also checked the dockers by `docker ps` , all are normal.

So I have no glue, what the source for the error could be.I will be happy about every help! **Thank you!!!**

Answer (score 2):

Initially after committing the chaincode, init must be performed first. To execute init, you just need to specify `--isInit` in the invoke parameter option. See the documentation below.
[fabric/peer/chaincode](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchaincode.html)

```sh
peer chaincode invoke \
    -o localhost:7050 \
    --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem \
    -C mychannel \
    -n basic \
    --isInit \
    --peerAddresses localhost:7051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
    --peerAddresses localhost:9051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
    -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

Comment: thank you. In my case, I don't need to execute init. Anyway I tried yours: `Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 5c8....: invalid invocation: chaincode 'basic' does not require initialization but called as init" `

Comment: i see, It's ambiguous right now, so I'll check it again tomorrow. It's not helpful, but unfortunate :(

Comment: Yeah it's a bit strange. So I followed completly this instruction: [link] (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html). So to invoke the chaincode is still not working.....But I can go further - actually to the end- without any problems in the instruction. So does it mean invoking the chaincode is not necessary ?   And @myeongkil kim Happy New Year to you!! (I still have some hours more to go)

Comment: What is the version of docker? Currently, gRPC-related issues are occurring in version >3.0.0, and it was confirmed that the fabric also has a dependency.

Comment: It's docker version: 19.03.8. So recording the fabric prerequisites it should be ok ("17.06.2-ce or later")

Comment: Docker desktop(3.0.0) has Docker Engine(20.10.0) It doesn't seem to be this problem.

Comment: If so, what are the `ccenv` and `baseos` docker image versions of chaincode? It is necessary to check whether the version of the peer and the version of the chaincode image specified in core.yaml are the same. If the chaincode image version is latest, you need to check whether the latest version is the same as the peer version value.

Comment: Thank you @myeongkil kim! It is working now :)